# How to include JAR to Liferay portlet in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, liferay, portlet

How to import jsoup.jar to Liferay portlet, through Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

liferay has ivy settings. you could just locate the ivy.xml file in your liferay-plugin-sdk-6.2 folder (this normally reflects in eclipse as a project folder with your version). add this line `<dependency org="org.jsoup" name="jsoup" rev="1.8.1"/>`
 and then build "all". You'll see it download the dependency. When done, navigate to liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/.ivy folder, look up the downloaded jar and copy it to your project's lib folder i.e /lib. Go to project properties, then Java Build Path. In the libraries tab, click Add JARs and navigate to /lib and add it.

Answer (score 5):

just copy your jar file into docroot/WEB-INF/lib folder of your portlet. if you create your portlet correctly using eclipse and Liferay IDE(plugin), eclipse automatically recognize your lib folder and jar files under it into classpath